# How to solve "The types of the parameter field and parameter field current values are not compatible" in Crystal parameter

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm getting the above error when passing parameter to Crystal Reports in VS 2008

This is how I do it:

```
reportPath = GetReportPath(ReportType);
CRReport.Load(reportPath);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CRReport;
AddParameterToReport("DocumentID", DocumentID);

ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = ConnInfo();
SetDBLogonForReport(connectionInfo, CRReport);
SetDataSetForMultipleSubReport(connectionInfo, CRReport);
```

`AddParameter()`:

```
ParameterFields parameterFields = CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo;
ParameterValues currentParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
ParameterDiscreteValue parameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

parameterDiscreteValue.Value = CRParamValue;
currentParameterValues.Add(parameterDiscreteValue);

ParameterField parameterField = parameterFields[CRParamName];
parameterField.CurrentValues = currentParameterValues;
```

And `ApplyingCurrentValues()`:

```
ParameterFields crParameterFields = CRReport.ParameterFields;
ParameterField crParameterField = new ParameterField();

try
{
    // loop through all the sections to find all the report objects 
    foreach (ParameterField crParameterField1 in crParameterFields)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CRReport.ParameterFields.Count; i++)
        {
            ParameterValues CrParaVals = new ParameterValues();
            DataDefinition CrDataDef = CRReport.DataDefinition;
            ParameterFieldDefinitions PFDefs = CrDataDef.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFields = CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo;
            crParameterField = crParameterFields[i];
            CrParaVals = crParameterField.CurrentValues;

            CRReport.DataDefinition.ParameterFields[i].ApplyCurrentValues(CrParaVals);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex = null;
}
```

Getting the above error in the highlighted line.

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

I have only on parameter field in my Crystal Report as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above Error was occurred due to mis match of value type in crystal report once i change ,it was working perfectly.

What i did is
Eg:
In crystal report  i have given the value type as number.but while passing i passed textbox value which is string type..so i have changed the value type as string in the Crystal report and sent string as a arguments which result in expected solution.

Answer (score 2):

We use Crystal Reports for all our reporting and we never send parameters to the report like you are trying to do. We simply set the parameter value, you appear to be adding a parameter instead of referencing an existing parameter.

```
CRReport.SetParameterValue("DocumentID", DocumentID);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check Your parameters Type in report..
and match with the form where you are passing.
I faced same issue. and solve this by comparing both ends.